# How to change all items values in a document.getClassName call (Without it just using the first elements value)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to change the individual product prices on my page, since the encoding is all messed up thanks to the e-commerce platform i use. I'm needing to split on a £ sign, which seems to work well for individual items

I've tried changing the way I do this by using getElementID, but it's no good due to how the e-commerce platform operates, and I can't change any backend stff.

```html
<div class="products-price">
    <!--START: ITEMPRICE-->
    <span class="subfix">[ITEMPRICE]</span>
    <!--END: ITEMPRICE--> 
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var total = document.getElementsByClassName('subfix')
    for (i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
        total[i].textContent.split('£')[1];
    }
});
```

Comment: You're not actually doing anything currently. `total[i].textContent.split('£')[1]` merely returns a value - it doesn't *set* anything.

Comment: To continue Ukanos' comment... and although that code returns a value, it doesn't return it _into_ anything - you don't assign it to a variable, or write it to the page, or anything at all. It just sits there doing nothing useful. In general a line of code is supposed to do something to alter the state of the program, otherwise what's the point of it?

Comment: I think maybe you've assumed that the `.split()` function mutates the original string, but it doesn't - it returns a new array containing the collection of split-out values. It's not possible for it to mutate the original value, even if we wanted it to, because it creates multiple values, not a single one. Logically it wouldn't make sense to put them back again. So instead you need to get the relevant item from the array of split results (using `[1]` as you do now) and then _write it back to the correct place in your page_.

Comment: P.S. " the encoding is all messed up thanks to the e-commerce platform i use" ... I find it hard to believe this error would not be fixable. I'm guessing it's something to do with UTF-8 or similar. A decent product should be able to work with that, unless it's really ancient or something. It's always better to fix a problem at source than to build in awkward work-arounds.

Comment: My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54669904/2813224) matches unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to set the text to that element

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var total = document.getElementsByClassName('subfix')

  for (i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
    total[i].textContent=total[i].textContent.split('£')[1];
  }



});
```

```html
<div class="products-price">
  <span class="subfix"> </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thankyou, for some reason it is iterating through alot. I'm printing the length.
Aka this is the console.

Comment: "prints of all correct information, an then"
12
12 undefined

Comment: Oh, it's running it for each element of 'subfix' which is a lot on some pages. How can i resolve this?

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName('subfix') it will select all the elements with that class name. post your html too. i will try to solve

Comment: Or put all the required element inside a div and only select the element in the div

Answer (score 0):

## `.split('£').pop();`

If you want the last element returned use `.pop()`, then overwrite the `<span>` with `.textContent` in same iteration. `.split()` can use regular expressions and regex can now match unicode. The following is a regex that matches a standard pound symbol and a full width pound symbol in unicode:

> ```
> /\u{a3}|\u{ffe1}/u
> ```

### Demo

```js
var total = document.getElementsByClassName('subfix')

for (i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
  var price = total[i].textContent.split(/\u{a3}|\u{ffe1}/u).pop();
  total[i].textContent = price;
  console.log(price);
}
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="products-price">
  <span class="subfix">£10.00</span>
  <span class="subfix">£53.00</span>
  <span class="subfix">£101.09</span>
  <span class="subfix">£90.01</span>
  <span class="subfix">£22.00</span>
  <span class="subfix">£18.55</span>
  <span class="subfix">£10.20</span>
  <span class="subfix">£70.67</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to change the price, but the currency symbol is what makes it difficult?

**You could acheive it like this:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var total = document.getElementsByClassName('subfix')
  for (i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
    var price = parseInt(total[i].textContent.split('£')[1])
    var newPrice = price + 5;
    total[i].textContent = "£" + newPrice;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="products-price">
  <span class="subfix">£4</span>
</div>
<div class="products-price">
  <span class="subfix">£8</span>
</div>
<div class="products-price">
  <span class="subfix">£32</span>
</div>
<div class="products-price">
  <span class="subfix">£2</span>
</div>
<div class="products-price">
  <span class="subfix">£12</span>
</div>
<div class="products-price">
  <span class="subfix">£6</span>
</div>
```